# How to save image in project folder in windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a image from contacts of phone , so I don't have its absolute path or Uri. How can i save it to my project Asset folder for further use? or 
can i save that image to my local database ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The asset folder is readonly, but you can save it to [Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localfolder).